# array not pulling all data from rss feed parser

Tags: jquery, arrays, xml, rss, feed

I am building an rss feeder and there are so many great resources out there, but literally not one of the pulls the SOURCE instead of AUTHOR. When I try to edit the code to pull the SOURCE, it displays as UNDEFINED. I see the SOURCE in the .rss file, but when I analyze the object in console, it does not actually retrieve the SOURCE data field.

Here is the found code I am trying to edit:

```
function parseRSS(url, container) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.responseData.feed);
      $(container).html('<h2>'+capitaliseFirstLetter(data.responseData.feed.title)+'</h2>');

      $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(key, value){
        var thehtml = '<h3><a href="'+value.link+'" target="_blank">'+value.title+'</a></h3><br/>' +value.source ;
        $(container).append(thehtml);
      });
    }
  });
}

function capitaliseFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Here is my .rss xml tree:

[RSS XML TREE: See the SOURCE node is there like all the rest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tiw5C.png)

Here is the console object:

[console object array showing that SOURCE is not being read by the parser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRNV6.png)

Any help is most appreciated! thank you!

Comment: here is the actual rss link: http://newsdesk-feeds.moreover.com/feed/a60eeb8d9fcdc35b.rss

Comment: Object {responseData: null, responseDetails: "The specified feed URL is invalid", responseStatus: 400} - i got this

Comment: @RadleyAnaya where do you mean exactly? this code works as is, its just not robust enough.

Comment: @RadleyAnaya i changed all the http calls to https and am still experiencing the same issue.

Comment: I am trying to use without the google service. I suspect that is "hiding" some nodes. I would rather get the whole xml doc as a string and parse it myself..just to be sure.

Comment: I also tried to use 'jsonp' as the data type. I am not using the service anymore though. You could try jsonp

Comment: i am not sure how to create a parser on my own, i need a client side solution, since the data is .xml i need a parser and converter to turn it into jsonp but i cannot find one.

Comment: I am working on it. The problem I am having is with CORS..as per usual >.<

Answer (score 0):

You can get the XML doc and parse it. Then you control what you see and don't see.

I think the problem with using a service is that they choose what is exposed, and it looks like source isn't one of them. I just decided to get the xml doc and parse it myself (example below - requires php). I hope this helps you.
I got the source by curling the xml document then turning it into a xml document using the SimpleXMLElement - then you can traverse it pretty easily:

```
<?php

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$sXML = get_data('http://newsdesk-feeds.moreover.com/feed/a60eeb8d9fcdc35b.rss');
//$sXML = get_data('http://alanstorm.com/atom');

echo $sXML;
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

foreach($oXML->channel->item as $oEntry){
    echo "<div style='background: red;'>". $oEntry->source . "</div>"; // your source

}
```

Here is the DOM inspected. You literally can get anything you want. Also there are libraries out there that will probably turn this into JSON for you. It wouldn't be hard to do it yourself though either.

[image]

Here is the output of sources:

[image]